# Why is 'nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches' increasing on isolated CPU

Tags: c++, c, linux, scheduler, interrupt

I have server with 2 isolated CPU (4 with hyperthreading):

`BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-4.4.0-72-generic root=/dev/mapper/valet--vg-root ro isolcpus=3,7,11,15 irqaffinity=0-2,4-6,8-10,12-14`

This is topology of my server:

Machine (39GB total)

```
  NUMANode L#0 (P#0 24GB)
    Package L#0 + L3 L#0 (12MB)
      L2 L#0 (256KB) + L1d L#0 (32KB) + L1i L#0 (32KB) + Core L#0
        PU L#0 (P#0)
        PU L#1 (P#8)
      L2 L#1 (256KB) + L1d L#1 (32KB) + L1i L#1 (32KB) + Core L#1
        PU L#2 (P#1)
        PU L#3 (P#9)
      L2 L#2 (256KB) + L1d L#2 (32KB) + L1i L#2 (32KB) + Core L#2
        PU L#4 (P#2)
        PU L#5 (P#10)
      L2 L#3 (256KB) + L1d L#3 (32KB) + L1i L#3 (32KB) + Core L#3
        PU L#6 (P#3)
        PU L#7 (P#11)
    HostBridge L#0
      PCIBridge
        PCI 8086:10c9
          Net L#0 "enp1s0f0"
        PCI 8086:10c9
          Net L#1 "enp1s0f1"
      PCIBridge
        PCI 15b3:1015
          Net L#2 "enp4s0f0"
          OpenFabrics L#3 "mlx5_0"
        PCI 15b3:1015
          Net L#4 "enp4s0f1"
          OpenFabrics L#5 "mlx5_1"
      PCIBridge
        PCI 102b:0532
      PCI 8086:3a22
        Block(Disk) L#6 "sda"
        Block(Disk) L#7 "sdb"
        Block(Removable Media Device) L#8 "sr0"
  NUMANode L#1 (P#1 16GB) + Package L#1 + L3 L#1 (12MB)
    L2 L#4 (256KB) + L1d L#4 (32KB) + L1i L#4 (32KB) + Core L#4
      PU L#8 (P#4)
      PU L#9 (P#12)
    L2 L#5 (256KB) + L1d L#5 (32KB) + L1i L#5 (32KB) + Core L#5
      PU L#10 (P#5)
      PU L#11 (P#13)
    L2 L#6 (256KB) + L1d L#6 (32KB) + L1i L#6 (32KB) + Core L#6
      PU L#12 (P#6)
      PU L#13 (P#14)
    L2 L#7 (256KB) + L1d L#7 (32KB) + L1i L#7 (32KB) + Core L#7
      PU L#14 (P#7)
      PU L#15 (P#15)
```

I have simple app like that:

```
main() {
    uint64_t cc = 0;
    while (1) { cc += 1; }
    return 0;
}
```

Running it with this command `taskset -c 7 ./app` I'm expecting that nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches on this process will be about 0 but it is:

`voluntary_ctxt_switches:        1
nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:     2589`

and increases by ~100 each second.

Also I'm expecting that voluntary_ctxt_switches will be exactly 0 because I don't execute any blocked calls.

I checked `/proc/interrupts` for CPU 7 and can see increase for next: `NMI, LOC, PMI, RES`.

So:

1) Why number of context switches is so high and what is exactly reason?

2) Am I right saying that NMI and PMI interrupts are harmless and not important?

3) Why I have high value for RES interrupts?

Waiting for your answer!

Comment: I assume nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches is the number of time slices are given to a process by CPU. I launched a single process on PC with lots of available CPU resources and have the same issue.

Comment: That is: your process exhausted CPU time quantum(inrcreasing nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches)  , rescheduling procedure was called, and your process was selected again